# How to upload photo to a server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am trying to upload a photo from my Vue frontend to the server.

```
 const fd = new FormData();
                fd.append('image', this.selectedFile)

                console.log(fd);
                axios.post(`/api/users/46/set-avatar`, fd)
                    .then(resp => {
                        console.log(resp);
                    })
                    .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Where `this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];` is the value of an uploaded image (via input type="file"). 
Sending this request I'm getting 400 error.
I'm not quite sure what the problem is, I alreay tried to send this.selectedFile, but It's not working anyway.

We are using swagger in the project and it says:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/api/users/45/set-avatar" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@nyc.jpg;type=image/jpeg"
Request URL
http://localhost:8080/api/users/45/set-avatar
```

Comment: Did you try setting the header? `axios.post('/api/users/46/set-avatar', fd, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })`

Comment: @NULL SWEΔT 400 error code